# Unable to understand the error with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, h.265

Can someone help me with the following FFMPEG error:

```
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ffmpeg version 4.4.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, hevc, from '/home/ubuntu/flixer/tmpofmcrjst/animation/input_clip.h265':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc), 3264x2448 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1200k tbn, 60 tbc
Input #1, hevc, from '/home/ubuntu/flixer/tmpofmcrjst/animation/animated_text_clip.h265':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2448x244 [SAR 1:1 DAR 612:61], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1200k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (hevc) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx265)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7e03080] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7e746c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+1-f0c1022b6
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 8.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(39 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00 
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-28.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock sao
Output #0, hevc, to '/home/ubuntu/flixer/tmpofmcrjst/clips/clip1.h265':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 3264x2448 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 60 fps, 60 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    9 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   19 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   25 fps= 15 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   27 fps=5.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   28 fps=5.3 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   29 fps=4.1 q=26.6 size=      69kB time=-00:00:00.01 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=   32 fps=4.2 q=38.9 size=      74kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=18296.1kbits/s speed=0.00436x    
frame=   33 fps=3.9 q=38.9 size=      75kB time=00:00:00.05 bitrate=12286.1kbits/s speed=0.00591x
```

I am a newbie and have been facing trouble to understand this above error. I am trying to overlay the `animated_text_clip.h265` on the `input_clip.h265` using the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) package in python. The package outputs error into STDERR and the above is the message I am getting.

Comment: Why do you think that's an error?

Comment: because it's in stderr and my program exits without doing what it is intended to do. Am I missing something here? @roaima

Comment: These logs doesn't indicate error - the only thing is a deprecated pixel format used, but that's not necessarily an error. It would be helpful if you edit your question describing what were you trying to achieve and providing details of the problem.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I have updated the question.

Comment: LeonardoAlvesMachado is correct. This is not an error. FFmpeg writes the log to `stderr`. This is normal.